# Would it be faster to create a read stream for each s3 getobject or do a promise all and convert each Body to a string?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting a dynamic amount of csv files where each file has around 1000 rows. The amount of files could range from 1 to 1000s. I'm wondering if it's faster to loop through each file with `getObject().createReadStream()` and pipe it into a csv parser. Or if I should do a promise all something like this:

```
const allObjs = await Promise.all(
    filePaths.map((file) => {
        return S3.getObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: file
        }).promise();
    })
);
```

And then loop through each response and convert the bodies into string and then pipe it into a csv parser from there? Is there a way to use the AWS Body property without converting it into string first?

I have working code for both just wondering what's the best way to execute this.